# Why does computer memory only have two states?

Tags: memory

Why do computers use binary, in the sense why do they use bits that can only represent a high and a low state? I was reading "Logic & Computer Design Fundamentals" (by M. Morris Mano, Charles R. Kime (Author), and Tom Martin) and don't understand their reason:

> consider a system with 10 values representing the decimal digits. In
>   such a system, the voltages available—say, 0 to 1.0 volts—could be
>   divided into 10 ranges, each of length 0.1 volt. A circuit would
>   provide an output voltage within each of these 10 ranges. An input of
>   a circuit would need to determine in which of the 10 ranges an applied
>   voltage lies. If we wish to allow for noise on the voltages, then
>   output voltage might be permitted to range over less than 0.05 volt
>   for a given digit representation, and boundaries between inputs could
>   vary by less than 0.05 volt. This would require complex and costly
>   electronic circuits, and the output still could be disturbed by small
>   “noise" voltages or small variations in the circuits occurring during
>   their manufacture or use.

So if it were possible to detect a 0.05v change accurately and shield against noise would we use computers with 10 states? If yes, than is it just a matter of inventing such equipment that can detect a 0.05v change? Why not just increase the scale; for example make the range from 0-50 volts and have a state every multiple of 5 (e.g. 0,5,10,15,...,50) and allow for a +/- 2V for noise?

Comment: Actually, there were decimal computers in the past. There were also analog ones, and ones that used water flows for calculation. I'd note that there's also devices that use 3 voltage levels.

Comment: There were "decimal computers" (and still are: most pocket calculators) but as I noted in my answer they still fundamentally used binary circuits, not ten different analog signal levels. They used either 10 bits in an only-one-at-a-time arrangement (a ring counter) or they used BCD or other coding to store a decimal digit in each set of four or five bits. Analog computers certainly exist but they are completely different things. As for "3 voltage levels" the third is most often a "tri-state" which means "I'm not actually asserting an output level right now".

Comment: The fundamental answer is this -- with only two states, no precision is needed. So long as you raise the voltage enough, you're in one state, and so long as you lower it enough, you're in the other. The absence of any need for precision permits high density, high efficiency, and high speed. There is no benefit to having more states that's worth that high cost.

Comment: I cannot believe such a bad question got all this attention: *So in the future..*, you don't call this **primarily opinion-based**?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Maybe it's a tiny bit opinion-based, but primarily? No.  Comparisons of circuit complexity, noise immunity, speed, and power consumption do not result in "opinions". If it were the case that binary logic lost on some comparisons and won on others, then you could say that it was opinion as to which "wins" were more important. But binary logic wins on _everything_. That's not opinion, it's solid engineering fact.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan ... none of which falls into the realm of `computer hardware or software, as defined in the help center`.

Comment: I see you have switched from arguing that is is "opinion-based"...  I'm not sure how the question _"Why does computer memory only have two states?"_ can be interpreted as not about computer hardware. I don't see any violation of http://superuser.com/help/on-topic either.

Answer (score 12):

The underlying reason is: It's easier to build two-state logic, and 99% of the time anything more complicated gives no practical advantage.

In fact, it's *far* easier (meaning smaller, cheaper, and more reliable) to build four memory units that each have two states (which can be used to store a decimal digit in BCD notation) than it is to build a single unit of memory that can store and read out 10 states.

Any future technology improvements might improve the 1-of-10 memory, yes. But, the same tech developments could be applied to binary circuits too, making them smaller, more reliable, and use less power. The binary circuits will improve faster than the one-of-ten-voltage-level circuits will, because the binary circuits perform a fundamentally simpler job. So the one-of-ten circuits can *never* catch up.

Using higher voltages is a non-starter. You'll increase power consumption; and the higher the voltages are in your signal lines, the more noise they radiate (so they're more likely to corrupt other signals). In fact, we are currently running signal traces so close to each other that at 50 volts you'd have to worry about arcing, not just capacitive coupling! The trend in modern CPUs is to use lower and lower voltages, not higher.

Besides, binary coding, though it seems strange upon first encounter, is extremely convenient in many ways. A binary adder circuit is a far, far simpler (and more reliable) design than an adder that would use varying voltage levels such as are described. (And I don't even want to think about how you'd do multiplication, division, or floating point.) Plus, you need binary digital logic to implement the rest of the computer's processor anyway.

The fact that humans prefer to deal with computers using decimal numbers is all but irrelevant: Conversion between binary and decimal is a trivial bit of code.

It's worth noting that there were a few very early computers that stored numbers as decimal digits. But they did not do it with varying voltage levels. Instead they used circuits called "ring counters" that were, in effect, ten bits of memory set up so that only one of the ten could be "1" at a time. (Look up "dekatron".)

There were later "decimal" computers like the IBM 1401 and IBM 1620, but again, they all fundamentally used binary storage. The bits were just used to represent decimal digits in various ways. e.g. the 1401 used "binary coded decimal" in which a set of four bits were used to code each decimal digit. Computers like this were very successful in their time, and most calculators still work this way.

In short, although decimal representation would seem to make more sense, that's really just because that's what we as a civilization are used to. Binary representation makes more sense for computer circuits by every measure of engineering. (And anyway, if we'd been a little smarter we'd have grown up using our fingers to count in binary, and we'd be able to count not just to 10 but to 1023! :) )

Comment: Yeah, the only 'pro' that could have would be to increase the bandwidth as storing 8 values per position would increase the bandwidth x4.

Comment: The bandwidth would in fact drop, because as soon as you would go to more complex data representation on you signal wires, they would become much more noise sensitive and you would have to decrease the transmission speed.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia Sorry, but no. The usable bit rate of a noisy channel (there is no such thing as a non-noisy channel) is dependent on the signal-to-noise ratio. If, using the same voltage range, you send one of eight values instead of one of two (essentially sending three bits at a time instead of one), your noise immunity gets _much_ smaller, resulting in lower SNR. So what you gain in bits-per-signal-transition you lose in the reliability of transmission - see the Shannon-Hartley theorem. (edit-added: smc posted quicker 'cause he posted shorter, but we're both saying the same thing. :)

Answer (score 6):

The article that you have quoted answers your question very well, you just have to give it a bit more thought.

Primary reasons for using binary  representation for electronic data storage and transmission is the complexity  level of the circuitry and noise margins.

Another important reason is that for the data storage purposes binary is the lowest common denominator. You can efficiently represent any data in binary without any overhead. Using more states than 2 would often result into the overhead when attempting to represent very simple (for instance binary) data

As for the last part of your question, I have to remind you that as electronic components industry progresses, we are moving towards lower voltages, not higher. Having 50 Volts at your computer main memory IO pins would be very impractical, dangerous and expensive. Modern computer memory usuauly uses something around 1.5V.

I recommend the following reading:

- https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap02/ch02_3.html
- http://nookkin.com/articles/computer-science/why-computers-use-binary.ndoc

Comment: you don't rebuttal the point that you could just use a larger voltage range...

Comment: Well, larger voltage range will result into larger max voltage, and this is highly impractical. I have addressed this in the fourth paragraph.

Comment: Larger voltage is more consumption. Think on Laptops and mobile phones.

Comment: @user119591: not necessarily, I have a geiger counter that runs for months on a small lithium battery and operates with 500V. The problem with higher voltages is really the slew rate when switching, and that is also the reason we use lower voltages these days. For every switching a transistor in a modren computer, we need to charge some capacitance, and the higher voltage we have to charge it to, the more amps we need to provide to do it in the same time. This leads to physical limitations.

Comment: Not only would 50 volts be dangerous and expensive, it would consume massive amounts of power and be incredibly slow.

Comment: "You can efficiently represent any data in binary without any overhead.".This is wrong, e.g. using fractional decimal digits means that you need a nibble (4 bits, 16 states) for each decimal digit (10 states). You need to use decimal digits because 0.1 cannot be encoded correctly in binary digits. The new packed decimal format reduces the overhead from 60% to 2.4% (1024 states for 1-1000) significantly, but it is still overhead.

Comment: @PlasmaHH The Geiger counter example does not prove that higher voltages don't necessarily mean higher current. The high voltage is used only to charge the anode of the G-M tube, an extremely high-impedance device. Only about 10 to the 10th electrons mpve out of the tube with each "click" - about half a millionth of a Coulomb. The only appreciable energy used is to either make clicks in your 'phones or move a meter needle. But that circuit is not anything like what you'd find in computer arithmetic circuits. The capacitance issues you mention are also true, of course.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz why would 50 volts be slow? Also I don't see your argument about being dangerous, any electrical appliance plugged into the wall has the potential to electrocute someone.

Comment: @Celeritas Why would 50 volts be slow? Why does it take longer to run 50 yards than 1 yard? The more you need to change the voltage, the longer it takes and the more power it takes (for constant resistance and capacitance). I didn't make an argument that it would be dangerous, I just acknowledged that other people did. But I can make the argument if you want me to -- it starts with understanding that computers are not like simple electric devices that can use large wires and thick insulation. They have to have parts that are very small and very close together.

Comment: @Celeritas, switching higher voltage is always slower than lower voltage. In fact the high operating frequences achieved in modern processors are largely achieved by reducing the voltage. For better understanding of basic electrodynamics, I recommend the following reading: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-1/electric-circuits/

Answer (score 1):

Memory is based on transistors, which while analog in nature, are used in a binary way and coupled to a clock signal (the MHz). The simplest memory to  be had is a J/K (Q/Q') flip-flop. This arrangement of 4 simple NAND gates is the fundamental bit of digital storage - it is what stores a 1 or a 0. The flip-flop has no ability to store non-digital or multiple values.

Another aspect is the clock signal, which provides the latching of values. There is a time when the values change that the output is indeterminate. The clock signal is chosen as to be slightly longer than the time it takes for the output to settle. This then latches the values and the computation proceeds. When values don't settle in time for the clock pulse, the wrong value gets carried forward and the computer crashes.